# iOS simulator: how to do a 2 finger single tap on a mac laptop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the iOS simulator, how to simulate a 2 finger single tap on a mac laptop?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Click while holding the option (alt) key.

Comment: Add the Shift key to do a pan.