# Simulate a 2 finger single tap on the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to detect gestures on a specific part of my screen close to the right hand most side.

When I try tapping using this approach ([iOS simulator: how to do a 2 finger single tap on a mac laptop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866423/ios-simulator-how-to-do-a-2-finger-single-tap-on-a-mac-laptop)), the two "fingers" appear at opposite ends of the screen.  How do I get the simulator to tap so that the "fingers" are next to each other.

Comment: (buy a second mouse?)

Comment: Thanks I tried the second mouse solution and it works ;) (just kidding)

Comment: Use Option key to show two fingers icons on simulator screen. Place them as close as you want them to be. Then press Shift to move them to wherever on the screen you want.

Comment: @Zen Neat!  I didn't know about using the shift key.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When in the simulator, hold the option key down and click - this will simulate a two-finger tap!

Answer (score 40):

Use Option key to show two fingers icons on simulator screen. Place them as close as you want them to be. Then press Shift to move them to wherever on the screen you want.

Comment: So user friendly UI, so obvious